# Rally SDK 2.0 JavaScript Query Filtering

Tags: rally

I'm trying to apply a filter in my UserStories. But the filters are not working and the query is returning all the stories from the selected project.

I'm using the following code:

```
var estimatedStoriesQuery = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
       model: 'UserStory',
       storeConfig: {
           filters: [
               {property: 'Project.Name',
                operator: '!=',
                value: 'null'},
               {property: 'PlanEstimate',
                operator: '!=',
                value: 'null'},
               {property: 'ScheduleState',
                operator: '=',
                value: 'Accepted'}, 
               {property: 'DirectChildrenCount',
                operator: '=',
                value: '0'},
               {property: 'AcceptedDate',
                operator: '<',
                value: 'LastMonth'}
             ]
           },});

estimatedStoriesQuery.load({
                    callback: function(records, operation) {
                        if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                           var estimatedStoriesCount = records.length;
                           document.write(estimatedStoriesCount);  
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Do you guys have any idea of what should be the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra nested storeConfig.  Get rid of that and you should be good:

```
var estimatedStoriesQuery = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
   model: 'UserStory',
   filters: [
       {property: 'PlanEstimate',
        operator: '!=',
        value: 'null'},
       {property: 'ScheduleState',
        operator: '=',
        value: 'Accepted'}, 
       {property: 'DirectChildrenCount',
        operator: '=',
        value: '0'},
       {property: 'AcceptedDate',
        operator: '<',
        value: 'LastMonth'}
     ]
 });
```

You shouldn't need the Project.Name filter since it's not possible to create a story that is not in a project.

Comment: Sorry, but it still not working. Am I loading the query correctly? Or doing the right way to count the stories?

Comment: This code seems like it's working for me.  What are you expecting to get back?  The filters as written return all accepted leaf stories that have a PlanEstimate set which were accepted prior to last month.  Is that what you're trying for?

Comment: The `if(operation.wasSuccessful())` condition is not being satisfied. Any idea?

Comment: If you open up the network tab in your browser's developer tools can you inspect the request and the response?  Any errors returned?

Comment: Yes. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`. Actually, i'm loading two different queries inside the `launch: function() {}`. I don't know how it can affect something but the other load method is working fine.

Comment: There are two issues with the code: 1) per Kyle's answer, please remove the nested store config (it is still in your code). Notice that Kyle's code does not have storeConfig inside the config. 2) use 2.0rc1 version of sdk instead of 2.0p4. DirectChildrenCount is not available in 2.0p4. After I made these two changes your code worked.